# If $A$, $B$, $C$ are three different numbers such that:

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $A$, $B$, $C$ are three different numbers such that:
$$AB+BA=BBC$$ then find $A$, $B$, $C$.

Just by hit and trial, I found $A=9$, $B=1$ and $C=0$. Is there a general method to approach problems.

Comment: $AB=BA=9$. LHS $=18$, RHS $=0$?

Comment: are they such as $A*B$?

Comment: @SahibaArora, What do you mean?

Comment: @haqnatural, No. they aren't..

Comment: @AlbertEinstein did you mean $AB-BA$ in the LHS?

Comment: @SahibaArora A, B, C are numbers at the respective places. i.e, the OP did not mean multiplication.

Comment: You can simplify it to $A=BC$ when $B\not=0$. So choosing $B$ and $C$ you got your unique $A$ for this triple. If $B,C\not=0,1$ and $B\not=C$ then you are sure they are different.

Comment: @SahibaArora, No. I mean $AB+BA$.

Comment: @AnanthKamath Thanks now I get it.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein you must clearly state what you intend to ask in the question itself.

Comment: @AnanthKamath, What's unclear in the question?

Comment: @AlbertEinstein I meant that you must specify that A,B and C are numbers at the respective places in the equation. I can understand that it is obvious from the format of the question, but it would be better to state the fact, neverthless. This should be done, so that the question would look more complete.

Comment: @AnanthKamath, I think anyone who understamds maths can interpret that "… are three different numbers…".

Comment: @AlbertEinstein I suppose there are many people who do not understamd maths as well as Albert Einstein.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2278952/period-of-a-sequence-defined-by-its-preceding-term   In this question, the OP(me) has stated that $x_0 \ne \sqrt3$, even though it is obvious. It is done for the sake of clarity only.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: write it as $$AB+BA=BBC\\ 10A+B+10B+A=100B+10B+C\\ 11A=99B+C\\ 11\left( A-9B \right) =C$$

Answer (score 1):

Since "$A, B,C$ are different numbers", why limit yourself to 1-digit numbers?

$$\begin{align*}
AB+BA &= BBC\\
10A + B + 100B + A &= 1000B + 100B + C\\
11A - 999B &= C
\end{align*}$$

One set of solutions is $A=92+i, B=1, C = 13+11i, i = 0, 1, \ldots, 7$. That gives
$$\begin{align*}
921+192 &= 1113\\
931+193 &= 1124\\
941+194 &= 1135\\
&\vdots\\
991+199 &= 1190\\
\end{align*}$$